# ValueError exception from a floor-division operation on a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am doing arithmetic on columns of a `DataFrame`. I get a `ValueError` exception when the size of the (sub-)`DataFrame` on which I operate exceeds a threshold.

As an example, consider the `DataFrame`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

random_list = list(np.random.randint(1, 30, 10000))
df = pd.DataFrame({"p": random_list, "q": random_list})
```

This operation works:

```
df[0:5000] // [2, 10]
```

but this one fails:

```
df[0:5001] // [2, 10]
```

with the exception:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10002,) (2,)
```

As soon as the slice generates a `DataFrame` of `len` greater than 5000, an exception will be thrown. The threshold depends on the number of columns. Considering instead a `DataFrame` generated from the dictionary:

```
{"p": random_list, "q": random_list, "r": random_list}
```

and a length-3 list for the floor division, the above operation will fail for any slice of length greater than 3334.

What is happening?

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: @GPhilo I have updated the post.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in that line of code?

Comment: @GPhilo I am taking the floor division by 2 of all values in the first column, and the floor division by 10 of all values in the second column.

Comment: what's `df.shape`?

Comment: @GPhilo (10000, 2).

Comment: Ok this is really confusing me too. If you do `df[0:5001].as_matrix() // [2, 10]`, it works If you try with the dataframe directly, it breaks. I tink there's something shady going on when the `//` operator is broadcasted to the array... although I always understood pandas uses the same conventions as numpy for broadcasting.

Comment: It is working with simple division.It has something to do with floor division.

Comment: Pandas is converting the list into an array and performing a broadcasted division across columns, and that for some reason isn't working.

Comment: very interesting error. The starting point is that in `pandas\core\ops` Exception Handling is triggered in `expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y,
                                          raise_on_error=True, **eval_kwargs)` of `_arith_method_FRAME.na_op` ; the operator `//` specifically triggers it in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deeper case goes way over my head, but I can tell you why the error happens.

In `pandas\core\computation\expressions.py` Line 31, the following constant is declared:

`_MIN_ELEMENTS = 10000`.

If the operation you try to perform exceeds this amount of elements to be evaluated, it will try to use the `numexpr` module to speed up computations. And while the floor division operator is supported in `numexpr`, the problem is that the expression is made into a `VariableNode` to be used in the expression, for which floor division is not supported. Keep in mind that for instance the `addition` operator is supported.

It stems from the following few lines:

```
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    __div__ = div_op
    __rdiv__ = binop('div', reversed=True)
```

In `numexpr/expressions.py`. The fun part is, that `__div__` and `__rdiv__` are never defined for `sys.version_info[0] >= 3`. If you add lines to implement these manually, your issue is solved. In other words: it is a bug in the `numexpr` module.

You can of course also declare `_MIN_ELEMENTS = 20000` or similar, to expand the limit before you run into the same error.

A word of caution: you really want to be careful with editing parts of these kinds of core modules, as fiddling around with them can break a lot of stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the two solutions, these will be useful. Thanks for the [report](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/issues/294) as well.